# Supabase realtime "error occurred when joining realtime:public:<Channel>"

Tags: postgresql, real-time, phoenix-framework, supabase, supabase-database

I upgraded from Supabase-Js v1 to v2. After doing so, my previously working realtime subscription all fail and create the following error:

**Question**

What does this error message mean? Why does the error occur and how could I fix it?

I think the table name is a channel.

```js
event: "phx_reply"

payload: 
response: {reason: "error occurred when joining realtime:public:<table-name>"}

reason: "error occurred when joining realtime:public:<table-name>"

status: "error" 

ref: "1"
topic: "realtime:public:<table-name>"
```

I found a similar error message here. However, I do not understand it. Although, I disabled Postgres Row Level Security:

https://github.com/supabase/realtime/issues/217

**My code**

You can find the full code here:

https://github.com/Donnerstagnacht/polity/blob/master/src/app/profile/state/profile.service.ts

**Table**

```js
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.profiles_counters
(
    "id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "amendment_counter" bigint   DEFAULT 0::bigint,
    "follower_counter" bigint  DEFAULT 0::bigint,
    "following_counter" bigint  DEFAULT 0::bigint,
    "groups_counter" bigint  DEFAULT 0::bigint,
    "unread_notifications_counter" bigint  DEFAULT 0::bigint,
    CONSTRAINT profiles_counters_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT profiles_counters_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES auth.users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.profiles_counters OWNER to postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.profiles_counters TO anon;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.profiles_counters TO authenticated;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.profiles_counters TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.profiles_counters TO service_role;
```

**Activating RealTime**

```js
begin;
  drop publication if exists supabase_realtime;
  create publication supabase_realtime;
commit;
alter publication supabase_realtime add table profiles_counters;
alter table "profiles_counters" replica identity full;
```

**Disabling Row Level Security**

```js
ALTER TABLE profiles_counters DISABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

**Creating Realtime Subscription**

```js
  getRealTimeChangesCounters(uuid: string): RealtimeChannel {
    const subscription = this.supabaseClient
    .channel(`public:profiles_counters`)
    .on('postgres_changes',
      {
        event: 'UPDATE',
        schema: 'public',
        table: 'profiles_counters'
      },
      payload => {
        console.log(payload)
      }
    )
    .subscribe()
    return subscription;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to a current supabase internal bug.

I used the local development setup based on Docker. However, the docker image of supabase seems to be behind the supabase remote version (which is the one described in the supabase documentation).

So the solution is to switch to supabase remote development and wait for a fix of the local supabase docker image.

Related issues:
https://github.com/supabase/realtime/issues/295
https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/9798